# RDLC Reports on Azure

Tags: dll, deployment, azure, report, rdlc

I am not able to render a RDLC report on azure premise.
But, on local premise it just works fine!

Inspite of adding the necessary dlls

`Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll`

and copying them locally by setting their property: `copy local = true.`

And also setting the .rdlc file's property

`CopyToOutputDirectory = CopyAlways` &
 `BuildAction=Content`

i get the error as:

```
Error:
An error occurred while processing your request.
```

I don't even get a detailed exception so as to debug on cloud. Any information on this is appreciated.

I have referred: http://architecturefabric.net/2011/06/17/deploying-a-web-site-to-azure-that-uses-the-embedded-reportviewer-control-in-local-processing-mode/

Comment: Also, can anyone please tell me the cost of using a .rdlc report on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - to deploy remotely you also require this file:
Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll

See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx

Also make sure you set copy local = true on the dll properties.

Your report settings are correct (again I had this issue to)

As a note Azure Web Sites do not support rendering to stream for PDF coversions (this probably only applies if you are using MVC) and you have to convert to a web role.
(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b4a6eb43-0013-435f-9d11-00ee26a8d017/report-viewer-error-on-export-pdf-or-excel-from-azure-web-sites?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview)